# How @JsonProperty working using jackson parser in android

Tags: android, json

In this below code, if I access `getBl_no ()` its correctly returning value. I don't know how it's working I didn't set bl_no anywhere is that Json property will set to that set method? Please anyone explain.

```
        @JsonProperty("BL_NO")
        private String bl_no;

        public String getBl_no() {
            return bl_no;
        }

        public void setBl_no(String bl_no) {
            this.bl_no = bl_no;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonProperty` annotation is where the magic happens! The JSON parser that you use reads the JSON property named `BL_NO` and assigns its value to the private instance variable `bl_no`. You don't even need a `setBl_no()` method for this to work.

`@JsonProperty` annotation lets you tell the JSON parser that while serializing or deserializing, the JSON property `BL_NO` should be tied to variable `bl_no`. That's how the variable gets initialized with a value even though you don't explicitly do it.